# way to store image on webserver

Tags: php, file

I want to store the images(.jpg) uploaded by user in a secure manner. I am confused which way to go for a better result and performance. Best options I could see are:

```
1. Store the images in database. 
//problem : database size get large. lagging performance 

2. Store them in a folder in encrypted manner. 
//problem : Encryption and decryption on large file slows it down.

3. Place the image as it is in a folder behind 'public_html' in root directory. 
//problem : I am unsure as they aren't encrypted.
```

**Which would be the better way or is there any other 'BEST PRACTICE' I am unaware about right now ?**

Comment: What kind of security are you try to achieve? What attacks are you afraid of?

Comment: If there will be a lot of large image files and you do not have a nice database backend, then definitely do not put them in DB (for some enterprise systems, it makes sense to use DB though).  Encryption I think is really not an option.  I personally would choose option 3.  System-level security is the primary concern at that point, although you would still need application-level security to make sure that authorized users are retrieving permitted images.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I am concerned about leakage. As they are private. So the security is also my major concern.

Comment: @Rahul: That's not "security", that's "access control". See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all a question of **what you want to do with it**, and **what you want to secure it against**.

I don't see any possible attack vector via images. So I see two possible options, but first, the basics:

You store the images themselves on the **file system**. Storing files in a relational database is very inefficient.

- You keep the file itself and rename it to the **MD5 or SHA1 hash of the contents**.
- A database entry **linking** to the file's location on the filesystem is created, along with any meta-data you may want (owner, color, categories, etc).
- The files are divided into folders based on the first letter of the hashes (if you have a **lot** of images, consider dividing it into directories based on two or three letters.

Now, depending on your access scheme, you can put the files publicly, and simply linking to them (because the filename is complicated, guessing it would be hard), or you can put the files outside the public root, and have a PHP file access them and serve them after verifying permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store them in a database. Put them in a web directory like **uploads** and secure them using .htaccess

```
deny from all
```

this will restrict access to them.

You should also take care of file names to avoid file naming collisions.

Comment: In some hosting plans, you MUST store things in the web directory and do as stated here with .htaccess.  If you have more control over the server, I highly recommend putting the images OUTSIDE the web directory to avoid some future mishap where whoops, you have accidentally lost the .htaccess file (due to upgrade or some other configuration changes) and now all these private files are exposed.  This is not possible when outside the web directory.

Answer (score 2):

Store your images in a protected directory and deny access by your `.htaccess`.
`deny from all`

As your users upload images, you should create unique file names in your image store. Then you can serve the images using an image handler using a specific image ID:

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type:image/jpeg'); 
    if(authorized && isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        flush();
        readfile('someimage' . $_GET['id'] . '.jpg');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## 3, store in a folder outside of the web root.

Make sure the directory is a configuration option since you might want to store on a separate machine in the future if the size is too big or if you grow your number of front end nodes.

2 Tips:

1. Rename the file to a GUID or something unique and store the real name in the database. This will prevent any duplicate file name collisions.
2. Create a folder system so not all files are in the same directory. There are limits to the number of files in a folder. And store the path in the database.
   (i.e. date base the folders [YYYY][MM][DD][File.Ext] )